# In Python, how to use a function (from COM) which requires byref parameter?

Tags: python

I need to call a function written in VB.net as part of my COM automation program.

The VB program requires a byref parameter, defined as

```
Function GetBeamWidth(ByRef pfBeamWidth As Single) As Integer
```

I tested the function in VB codes shown below, no problem at all,

```
Dim y As Single
myObject.GetBeamWidth(x)
'myOject is an instance of the ActiveX server object, which implements function GetBeamWidth
```

however, I don't have a clue on how to call this function in python. Everything I tried gave me "type not match" error. I am sure that I loaded the ActiveX server, tried early and late binding, tried passing x with the definition of x = [0].

I also tried ctype.byref(x), not working. The example I found online is not that easy to understand. If ctype.byreg is the cure, can someone here paste an easy-to-follow example?

I guess this must be a common problem for yo all experienced programmer out there. I know python doesn't support pointer, but sadly in real life we have to interface with functions written by others/other languages which need passing function parameters by reference.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is a shot in the dark, but QueryInterface ? http://docs.activestate.com/activepython/2.4/pywin32/html/com/win32com/HTML/PythonCOM.html

Answer (score 0):

ByRef is passing by pointer, you can look at ctypes. It also exports [byref](http://docs.python.org/2/library/ctypes.html#passing-pointers-or-passing-parameters-by-reference).

Comment: Thanks for advice! sadly, still not working, now the error is: "TypeError: Objects of type 'CArgObject' can not be converted to a COM VARIANT"

Answer (score 0):

Finally, it turns out to be pretty much impossible to accomplish what I asked for. Alternatively, I wrapped my core functions in Python class and register it as COM server.

Then, I just built the most outside shell in VB.net, which loads all COM servers, provides UI, and simply calls COM functions to do the work.

I guess that is one of reasons for why we have programming platforms other than Python still alive.